# Where to find all the options for module.config.php?

Tags: zend-framework2

I play around with the latest ZF2 possibilities, but its kinda hard to find all the options you can define in the module.config.php

An example:
Which options has the view_manager:
I can open Zend/Mvc/View/Http/ViewManager.php and grep for all $this->config[*] to find them, but I'm sure there are more options for the ViewManager.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

TIA

**EDIT:** see http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/zendservicemanager-configuration-keys/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't find an overview on **all** possible options for module.config.php as you can basically override every possible configuration of every possible module inside your modules config.

If you're looking for configuration on certain objects you can take a look at the [official documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#usage) (linked is config for Zend\View) or check out possibilities from within the class files itself.

Documentation will greatfly improve over the next couple of months since ZF2 will leave RC status pretty soon.